# Backing up and applying custom keyboard shortcuts with ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shortcuts

Is there a way to backup tool shortcuts defined through the Customize -> Keyboard method in ArcMap 10.7?

The shortcuts saved seem to be specific to the map document and not application wide. I'm looking to use these shortcuts in multiple maps without having to initiate them each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you need to change the default options in the customize dialog, the defaults are these:

[image: Customize dialog]

Untick this and customisation is stored in the normal template which is inherited by all MXD's

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much.